# Should I write go down into the valley or down into the valley?

Tags: meaning-in-context

- We followed the footpath across the field and down into the valley.
- We followed the footpath across the field and went down into the valley.

What is difference in meaning above two sentences?

Comment: (1) has the coordination 'We followed the footpath [across the field] and [down into the valley].' // (2) has the coordination '[We followed the footpath across the field] and [Ø went down into the valley.] where Ø is the symbol for 'nothing actually here, but something really is {in this case the deleted subject of the second main clause, 'we'}'.

Comment: In the first, the footpath is taking you down.  In the second, the footpath is only taking you across the field and it is ambiguous whether it also goes down or not.

Comment: did the footpath get you down into the valley? if so first is fine

Comment: Dear John. I suspect that you may find our sister site [ell.se] more suitable for this kind of question.

Answer (score -1):

In the first, it could be construed as following the path with your eyes.

In the second, you followed the footpath across the field which led you down into the valley.

Comment: The first *could* be construed as following the path with your eyes, but in practice it would not be.

Answer (score -1):

What you should write depends on the actual surroundings in which you place the action and the action itself; from the second sentence it is clear that the action considered includes going down the valley and so we can presume that in the first sentence this action is understated since you are considering either sentence to relate to the same action; if the footpath has a continuation out of the field and into the valley then it doesn't matter which you write as far as meaning goes; you remain true to the facts. However, if the footpath stops at the end of the field and it is necessary so as to continue towards the valley from that point on, for instance, to do some climbing down of rocks , then you can't use the first one since that first one implies the same footpath leads down into the valley.

The reason for that is that you have to consider "the footpath across the field and down into the valley" as a noun phrase in which are found two  prepositional complements linked by the conjuction of coordination "and": the noun phrase can be paraphrased as "the footpath that went across the field and (then) that went down into the valley".